# Trying to bind data from DropDownList in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, bind

I am trying to bind data from DropDownList in ListView in EditItemTemplate but it didn't work.

Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("type")%>'>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Fatwa" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Interviewer" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Programs" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code working well but I forgot to type DataKeyNames in listview :D

```
<asp:ListView ID="TodayOrdersList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID">
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Shennigans.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample of concept you can use:

```
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="DataLabel" runat="server" Text="<% $resources:AppResource,UserData %>"
            CssClass="OneColumnTitleLabel"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" CssClass="RightColumnLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Resources.AppResource.Email + ":" %>'></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="RightColumnText" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'
            ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="LanguageLabel" CssClass="RightColumnLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Resources.AppResource.Language + ":" %>'></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="LanguageDropDown" runat="server" CssClass="RightColumnDropDown"
            DataSourceID="LanguageDataSource" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LanguageId") %>'
            AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" Selected="True">
            </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="RightColumnLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Resources.AppResource.Company + ":" %>'></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="CompanyTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="RightColumnText" Text='<%# Bind("Company") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="PhoneLabel" CssClass="RightColumnLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Resources.AppResource.Phone + ":" %>'></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="RightColumnText" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="UpdateUserData" runat="server" Text='<%# Resources.AppResource.Save %>'
            CssClass="Button" CommandName="Update" CausesValidation="true" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Take notice on LanguageDropDown (LanguageId is binded back to listview). This dropdown is binded to datasource like this one:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="LanguageDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLanguages"
    TypeName="GP.Solutions.Services.LanguageManager"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

This is how you can bind dropdown inside listview.